# Sweden flag--background

Tags: css

I am brand new to CSS. I want to make the background of my web page the flag of Sweden. I could probably go out and import an image, but I wanted to code it up myself for practice. I am able to get the blue background on the page, but how would I go about making the gold cross on the flag?

Comment: If you want to code it up yourself for practice. Then try. When/if you fail post what you tried and we will guide you in the right direction. http://www.whathaveyoutried.com?

Comment: You have a point. I will try doing that more in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a try: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/UvuQt/3/show/). You can view source here: [another little link](http://jsfiddle.net/UvuQt/3/). This might not be perfect, though!

CSS used to create that:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
body {
    background-color: blue;   
}
body:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    height: 100%;
    width: 10%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 25%;
    margin-left: -5%;
    background-color: yellow;    
}
body:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0px;
    margin-top: -5%;
    background-color: yellow;  
}
```

I hope that helped in any manner!

Comment: Clever, and a nice solution. Well done.

Comment: This looks great. If you don't mind me asking, what exactly does body:after do?

Comment: `body:after` inserts a "virtual" (somehow) element after `body` and lets you style it.

Comment: so it doesn't require an html element to be created for it to work. Neat!

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do this

```
.flag-background { position: relative; background: blue; width: 150px; height: 100px; }
.horiz-cross { width: 100%; height: 10px; background: yellow; position: absolute; top: 50px; }
.vert-cross { height: 100%; width: 10px; left: 50px; background: yellow;position: absolute}​

​<div class="flag-background">
<div class="horiz-cross"></div>
<div class="vert-cross"></div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/chadpeppers/sYeTq/
    This is very basic but it would get you started